# Can I share a Git repository stored in my computer so that somebody on the internet can clone it?

Tags: linux, git, server, repository

For a job/learning purpose I was asked to create a Git server. The idea is to create a repository stored in my computer that can be cloned over the internet. The thing is I am pretty new to servers so any indications, tips or advice to accomplish this are appreciated. I was told I could do it with Apache or Nginx and no port-forwarding was required.

Answer (score 0):

1. Apache|Nginx (which are another, different world of knowledge) is **The Bad Idea (tm)** for "a job/learning purpose" (except case purpose is a "billet of DevOps" and question, respectively, have to be placed on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/))
2. For easy, fast, almost no-brain deployment and launch of RO Git-server *without heavy dependencies* you can start from reading about [Git daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon) or [Soft Serve](https://github.com/charmbracelet/soft-serve) or [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) or maybe even get "own Github" with [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)